# Need your help in how to link a check box with macro

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox, google-sheets-formula

I have some check boxes in google sheet, and I need if I checked some of it (1 of pic) then run macro do the next copy specific cells with its formats (2 of pic) and paste it in the cell beside the check box(3 of pic)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you ([No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)). Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: First, search on how to lunch a script when you check the ckeckbox (indication: see  `onEdit(e)` function). Second, search how to copy a range (indication: see `copyTo`). Then try to assy both functions ... and come again with your errors if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by onEdit() trigger.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = e.source.getActiveSheet(), r ;
  var shtn=s.getName();
  if(shtn=="Sheet4") { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    r = e.range; 
    var linecol = r.getColumn();
    var linerow = r.getRow() ;
    //Browser.msgBox(linecol);

    if(linecol == 1 ) { //checks the column A
    //Browser.msgBox(linecol);
    s.getRange('B'+linerow).activate();
    s.getRange('B3:F3').copyTo(s.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
    var colfs=s.getRange("I:J").getFormulas();
    //Browser.msgBox(colfs);
    for (i=linerow-2; i>2; i--){
      if (colfs[i][0]!==""){//chk if there is a formula
        //Browser.msgBox(i+"  ---  "+colfs[i][0]);
        break;
      }
    }
    s.getRange('I'+linerow).setValue("=sum(I"+(i+1)+":I"+(linerow-1)+")")  ;
    }//chk col
  }//chk sheet1
}
```

If you share a sheet link with public edit rights, you will get the help quickly

Check my sample sheet here

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16XwVAF6DqIaREA9Cvxz2IvsON5vFJc0gJjHHPR9ZKH4/edit?usp=sharing

You need to authorize the script

Comment: You did a really great job, but i still have a last problem, if you have solve for it you will save me the problem is the row we have copied it with this macro has function 
for example  "sum" function  I want it to run on all previous row until the row has previous function

Comment: I'm not able to understand your requirement. I'm sorry. Can you feed some actual values with formulas in the sample sheet I made? Then probably, I can help you. Do you want to copy a formula (sum) in the source range to destination range and it should sum all previous rows in the same column? It is possible...... Or do you want a sum formula in the destination to calculate sum of all values in the same column upto previous row?..... Both are possible

Comment: I did feed some actual values with formulas in the sample sheet you made,
the problem in the source range, it has sum function which sum specific above cells, but I don't want that I need sum function "sum all above values until it find another function then stop summing "

Comment: I edited the answer. It is working in sheet also

Comment: I'm so sorry for your effort, but still that not what I mean.
I'll try to be more clear, 
for example >> I want to copy the sum function in F7 to more than place in F column, but the problem is the sum function in F7 just calculate the 5 cells above, when I copy it in another place in F column I want it to calculate all above values but will stop when find the previous Sum function, because of I will repeated it more than time in this column.

Comment: I edited again. You can check it in sheet also

Comment: You did really great job, that was an amazing code, thank you very match, kindly check the last note at your sheet.

Comment: I modified the script again

Comment: You did a great cod, thank you.